# Django and GoogleAppEngine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have some experience with Python and Flask. As part of an interview, I need to make a simple django app that will be deployed on GAE and also use Google Datastore.

I am in the process of breaking down my task and want to ask the following.

If I just work on the app for now, (using mongo), will deploying on GAE be straight forward? Or am I better understanding how GAE works, and how django works, and then start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. None of these things will help. GAE doesn't use Mongo, and Django doesn't directly integrate with Mongo anyway. There is no point writing an app using either Mongo or plain Django or if you want to deploy to GAE.

There are various projects that integrate Django with GAE - the old django-nonrel, and the newer [Djangae](https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae) - and you must absolutely start with those.

Comment: Yes I have seen both of them, I just wasn't sure if I have to start from there, or can add them in the end. You seem confident so I'll take your advice.

Comment: absolutely take his advice.